# What signal is passed to child process on terminating main program?

Tags: python, windows, signals, process-management

On a Windows 7 machine:-

- I have a main (Python) program that I start on a command prompt [main process].
- This program spawns a child (Python) program [child process].
- I close the command prompt.

Result:-

- Child process ends immediately.

On the other hand if I end the main program from task manager, I observe that the child process is still running.

I was wondering why the 2 approaches do not have the same results? Is it sending some different signal in the two cases?

Comment: Which platform are you working on? If it's POSIX, when a controlling process exits, the SIGHUP (hangup) is sent to all its child processes (which may or may not actually terminate them). Presumably, in the 'task manager' environment, the parent process is not made into a controlling process.  See [Consequences of Process Termination](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html) and related information.

Comment: AFAIK when you close a terminal it closes all processes attached to it. You should detach the child process from the terminal (e.g. daemonizing it).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using windows(win7) OS. Went through your referenced doc, it deals majorly with POSIX signal handling.

Comment: @Bakuriu Dont find any way to do the same in windows. The only thing I can do is make a service for the child process. But I want to avoid that stuff. Is there still something that helps? :(

Comment: That's why it is important to identify where you are working. The rules are radically different, and what applies to Unix (POSIX, Linux) does not necessarily apply to Windows, and vice versa.

Comment: The child process is assigned to the command window when it is launched.  The Windows API allows you to specify that the child process get a new window, or no window.  Hopefully, Python provides you with the same options when launching new processes.  (The Windows API also allows a program to change command windows after being launched, but I have no idea whether Python exposes that to the programmer or not.)

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston. Your suggestion helped a lot. Should have figured that myself. Yes Python provides the same. It solved my problem. Will post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments to the question pointed me to get the answer.

I was using `subprocess.Popen(args)` to spawn the child process. This would spawn the child process successfully but the child process would be launched in the same command window as its parent.

Going through [subprocess Popen doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), I found some additional arguments to be passed in order to launch child process in another command window.

Launching the child with the following arguments solved my problem.

```
subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

The last argument subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE is only for windows.